# Need to figure out this source code of freebase quad rdfize

Tags: rdf, freebase

I have looked all over internet but found only [this](http://code.Google.com/p/freebase-quad-rdfize/) single piece of source code that seems to convert freebase quad data to rdf triples.

I checked out this source code using tortoiseSVN and tried running it in Netbeans 7 (with pre-installed maven). I am getting the following error.

```
Data Transformation module ........................ SUCCESS [3.959s]
data-transformation ............................... SUCCESS [3.467s]
freebaseRDFizer ................................... FAILURE [0.442s]
index ............................................. SKIPPED
util .............................................. SKIPPED
Failed to execute goal on project freebaseRDFizer: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.sj.freebase.data.rdf:freebaseRDFizer:jar:0.1: Failure to find com.sj.freebase:util:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in http://freebase-Java.Googlecode.com/svn/repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of freebase-Java has elapsed or updates are forced
```

What I need is to figure out a way to utilize freebase quad dump to build an internet application. I dont want to use their API. Please guide me in right direction.

Comment: A simple typo in the POM isn't really an appropriate justification for a StackOverflow question, my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Maven question, not a Freebase or RDF question.  There's a bug in the project where the "utils" are referenced as "util".  Fix that and it will build.

Comment: I know it was a little newbie question, but I was not able to understand this source code related to freebase and rdf. Yes I should have tagged it as a maven question also. Sorry about that. But thanks anyway.